# How to get max value out of two max values

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How can I find the maximum value from similar fields in different tables?

```
select max(select max(col) from table1,select max(col) from table2...) from dual
```

Doesn't work! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use `GREATEST` function which returns the maximum from parameters:

```
SELECT
    greatest(
        (SELECT max(col) FROM table1),
        (SELECT max(col) FROM table2),
         ...
    )
FROM dual
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with UNION:

```
SELECT max(cols) FROM(
    SELECT max(col) as cols from table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT max(col) as cols from table2)
```